# How to write an AutoIt script to run an executable file from local to another location

Tags: autoit

Here is what I run in the DOS command

```
c:\folder\a.exe d:\ E:\
```

But how do I use [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) to write a batch file to run it?

Comment: If you are willing to use AutoHotKey instead, I might be able to help. "what have you tried?" will follow, though.

Comment: You cannot use a simple batch file for that?

Comment: Your question is very unclear and there's no hint that you've already taken some effort to try to solve your problem. You should improve this... And it's not obvious whether you want to automatically create a batch file containing your command or if you try to create an AutoIt script performing the exact same command.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty unclear and vague, so it really doesn't qualify for great tips... anyway, some help:

- You can either just run the exact same command via AutoIt like `Run("c:\folder\a.exe d:\ E:\")`.
- Or you can write this command into a batch file **command.bat** with `FileWrite("command.bat", "c:\folder\a.exe d:\ E:\")` like you asked for literally. Finally you can run this batch file with `Run("command.bat")`, this will open a command prompt for you... At last you can first save the filename into a variable with `$batchfile = "command.bat"`, secondly  `FileWrite($batchfile, "c:\folder\a.exe d:\ E:\")` and at the end `Run($batchfile)` to avoid redundancy.
- The best help is to read the documentation of [Run](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Run.htm). There you will find a perfect explanation of how to run dos commands: `Run(@ComSpec & " /c " & 'commandName', "", @SW_HIDE)` - you can omit the last two parameters if you want to see the command prompt. If you need a specific working directory, just type it as the second parameter.